# How to use events and event handlers inside a jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery-plugins, event-handling, jquery

I'm triyng to build a simple animation jQuery-plugin. The main idea is to take an element and manipulate it in some way repeatedly in a fixed intervall which would be the fps of the animation.

I wanted to accomplish this through events. Instead of using loops like for() or while() I want to repeat certain actions through triggering events. The idea behind this: I eventualy want to be able to call multiple actions on certain events, like starting a second animation when the first is done, or even starting it when one animation-sequence is on a certain frame.

Now I tried the following (very simplified version of the plugin):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.animation = function() {
        obj = this;
        pause = 1000 / 12; //-> 12fps

        function setup(o) {
            o.doSomething().trigger('allSetUp');
        }

        function doStep(o, dt) {
            o.doSomething().delay(dt).trigger('stepDone');
        }

        function sequenceFinished(o) {
            o.trigger('startOver');
        }

        function checkProgress(o) {
            o.on({
                'allSetup': function(event) {
                    console.log(event); //check event
                    doStep(o, pause);
                },
                'stepDone': function(event) {
                    console.log(event); //check event
                    doStep(o, pause);
                },
                'startOver': function(event) {
                    console.log(event); //check event
                    resetAll(o);
                }
            });
        }

        function resetAll(o) {
            /*<-
                reset stuff here
            ->*/
            //then start over again
            setup(o);
        }

        return this.each(function() {
            setup(obj);
            checkProgress(obj);
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Then i call the animation like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#object').animation();
});
```

And then – nothing happens. No events get fired. My question: why? Is it not possible to use events like this inside of a jQuery plugin? Do I have to trigger them 'manualy' in $(document).ready() (what I would not prefer, because it would be a completely different thing – controling the animation from outside the plugin. Instead I would like to use the events inside the plugin to have a certain level of 'self-control' inside the plugin). 
I feel like I'm missing some fundamental thing about custom events (note: I'm still quite new to this) and how to use them...

Thx for any help.

**SOLUTION:**

The event handling and triggering actually works, I just had to call the checkProgress function first:

Instead of

```
return this.each(function() {
  setup(obj);
  checkProgress(obj);
});
```

I had to do this:

```
return this.each(function() {
  checkProgress(obj);
  setup(obj);
});
```

So the event listening function has to be called before any event gets triggered, what of course makes perfect sense...

Comment: You created new event but i dont see event when they should be fired. Use click or so on and in its  the body fire you custom event

Comment: Your code only declare, but how and when thay should be fired? And you can use trigger in any script it doesnot deppend on widget or not. Widget is js too ))))

Comment: Well maybe that is the thing I don't understand right about events but I thought the events would be fired through the functions via trigger() starting with the call of setup() in return this.each().

Comment: Element doesnot have event 'allSetup', 'stepDone','startOver' so they dont work. you should use "native" event mouseover, keyuo so on. Native event is bridge for your custom event . Example: $('.elemt').on('mouseover',function(){$(this).trigger('startOver') })

Comment: Now I am completely confused. Right here: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/
trigger() is used like this: 
$('#foo').bind('custom', function(event, param1, param2) {
  alert(param1 + "\n" + param2);
});
$('#foo').trigger('custom', ['Custom', 'Event']); – no native event used...

Comment: Yes, but dom element does not have 'custom' event, so in this example this triger fire with code.

Comment: I fire the trigger with code too...

Answer (score 1):

You need set event on your DOM model for instance:

```
$('#foo').bind('custom', function(event, param1, param2) {
    alert('My trigger')

});

$('#foo').on('click', function(){  $(this).trigger('custom');});​
```

You DOM element should know when he should fire your trigger.

Please note that in your plugin you don't call any internal function - `ONLY DECLARATION`

Comment: So triggering the events through a function does not work? Because that is what I'm trying to do... I don't want any mouse or keyboard events for triggering my events... when you look at my code: I first declared the function setup() in which the event 'allSetup' gets fired at the end of the function. The function gets called in the plugin's return this.each() function, which gets called when using the plugin on my dom element inside of $(document).ready() function. In my understanding the event 'allSetup' should get fired when dom is ready and the plugin was used on dom element...

Comment: Or in other words your example should also work like $('#foo').doSomejQueryStuffHere().trigger('custom'); or am I wrong?

Comment: ah ok, then it is possible that 'doSomejQueryStuffHere()' prevents that trigger() calls the event on my dom object?

Comment: You are wrong btw., I do not only declare the functions I also call the relevant inside the "return this.each(function() {})" (you have to scroll down a little inside the sample code box, maybe you have not seen this). As you can see in my edited question, I found the solution (which was pretty banal). But thx for your help anyway.